# What do we do with users who ask questions but never vote?

Tags: discussion, users

I came across [this user](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3998/coldshine)'s profile, because under the user name it says **in red** "0% accept rate". It appears that he not only never accepted an answer, but never even voted for any answer.
First, this time the red text drew my attention, but I have no idea if I missed this before. Also it says 0% accept rate, but there's also the 0% voting rate. And that's something which isn't shown.

My feelings: "You're not cooperative, I don't want you here. And I'm certainly not going to answer your question."

1. Should answerers be better warned of this kind of users, or is the current warning sufficient?
2. Should such users be sanctioned, for instance by disallowing further questions until for instance a question is accepted or two votes are cast?

Comment: look up number of votes for some of our higher rep users, you might be surprised by patterns. 3 of our "higher" rep users almost never vote.

Comment: @Kortuk - But I would expect at least that they vote on the answers to their own questions. Oh, right, I see, there are those who never asked a question... :-). I always wonder what it would be like to know everything ;-)

Comment: I'm probably one of those guilty of not voting much.  I prefer to contribute by answering, and reserve voting for exceptional cases, both positive and negative.  At least a couple of times I have upvoted someone else's answer to the same question I answered when I thought they went particular above and beyond.  On the flip side, I've only downvoted answer I thought were outright wrong or misleading, or questions I felt were particularly poorly worded, out of place, or inappropriate.  I've voted to close a lot more than downvoted questions.

Comment: I would just leave a respectful comment indicating that they *can* accept and vote -- perhaps linking to the [faq#howtoask] -- only when it is clear they are not.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this user isn't aware of the etiquette of accepting the best answer if it provided at least a reasonable level of help.  I know it explains this in the FAQ, but I get the feeling too many people don't read it.  Perhaps the system should send a automatic nag email if you have not accepted a answer after something like 2 days and you've gotten at least one response.  This doesn't force you to accept if you feel none of the responses helped or actually answered your questions, but at least you will know that you should if one did.

Comment: I like the nag email idea. I know a lot of people hate getting emails like that, but it would be helpful for me at times.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, If you do not vote on qustions it nags you with a popup, why not for accepting answer also! Emails are a bad idea in my opinion as they often frustrate users, I have left two sites that sent me emails too often without my right to opt-out.

Answer (score 3):

Notice this user hasn't asked any question for several months.  I'd say they sanctioned themselves.

There are several ways of contributing to the site.  Asking questions is a very small contribution, but it is a contribution.

My advice:  If the question is interesting to you, answer it.  We're all here because we enjoy electronics, right?

Comment: Voting to me is like saying "thank you", accepting is "thank you so much" :-). Saying nothing seems rude to me, and if I get the impression that he doesn't care, I don't feel encouraged to answer.